# iphone multiple UITableviewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iphone programming. How do i create multiple tableviewcontroller without creating too many class files.
Like in iphone safari bookmarkbar with every new folder created it,  creates file and pushes. it will keep on creating tableviews.
How to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create/code a single class representing your generic UITableViewController, and then create multiple instances of it. For example, the original UITableViewController subclass loads to show the first page, then when a row is tapped, in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, instantiate another instance of your UITableViewController subclass and push it onto the navigation stack.
Remember your object oriented programming techniques here, a class is not an object, an object is an instance of a class, and there can be many instances of a class, which is what you need to achieve here. 

Here's some sample code:

MyTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

MyTableViewController.m

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
            self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //HERES THE IMPORTANT PART FOR YOU
    //SEE HOW I'M JUST CREATING ANOTHER INSTANCE OF MasterViewController?
    //You can tap the rows in this table until memory runs out, but all I have is one table view controller
    MyTableViewController *newController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Click Me", @"Click Me");
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: thanks for reply. if you don't mind can you show me some sample code.

Comment: Just added some sample code for ya.  Let me know if I can provide further detail

Comment: i have understood the code included in didselectrowatindexpath keeps looping between these two controllers. but what i want is for example in main tableview user selects 
one row it pushes to another controller. in this controller user creates a "one" item and it should push "one" another controller say third controller. in thirdcontroller if user 
creates two items say "one" and "two". The "one" should push fourth controller with empty tableview and for "two" it should push fifth controller with empty tableview.  
in all the tableview data will be different.
Thanks

Comment: any help please. banging my head on this for a week still cannot figure out how to do this. i can able to go three levels of tableviews with different data after that how to access third levels didselectrowatindexpath. stuck here. thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'll post an updated solution around 6pm est tonight. Meanwhile, could you post an example of the data structure you are usin to pass amongst these view controllers?

Comment: i have firstviewcontroller with array in didselectrowatindexpath i push normaly like {secondViewController*controller = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibname:"@secondview", bundle:nil];[self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:controller animated:YES];. In secondviewcontroller in didselectrowatindexpath i push like {secondviewcontroller *secondController = [[secondViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibname:@"secondview" budle:nil];

Comment: secondcontroller.string = secondViewString; [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];. How can i access the method of didselectroeatindexpath for currently pushed view? I want to keep on creating tableviews with different data. if the tableview has one row of data it should push one level of tableview. thank you.

Comment: I'm still having so much trouble trying to figure out exactly what are trying to do.  What do you mean "if the tableview has one row of data it should push one level of tableview"?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. what i mean was when you create a newfolder it adds to the tableview and it should push with empty tableview. in this tableview again user creates another newfolder it should push with another empty tableview. thank you